# What could cause an incomplete XML to JSON conversion when using JsonReaderWriterFactory and DataContractJsonSerializer?

Tags: c#, xml, json, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I am using the JsonReaderWriterFactory class to convert an XML string to a JSON string but this currently converts some of the string to JSON (but incorrectly, setting each field to null) and leaves the rest as XML.

My input XML is:

```
<Consignment>
    <id>c9c47490-cf0c-4ae1-bc0e-cfd015eb5c4a</id>
    <name>10/10/2014 15:43</name>
    <type>OUTLET</type>
    <date>2014-10-10T14:43:14</date>
    <outlet_id>b8ca3a6e-72c0-11e4-efc6-455d6c2bd6f0</outlet_id>
    <source_outlet_id>b8ca3a6e-72a9-11e4-efc6-50575111ef92</source_outlet_id>
    <status>SENT</status>
    <products>
        <id>c9c47490-cf0c-4ae1-bc0e-cfd015eb5c4a</id>
        <product_id>b8ca3a6e-72c0-11e4-efc6-455d6c241252</product_id>
        <name></name>
        <count>2</count>
        <received></received>
        <cost>4</cost>
    </products>
    <products>
        <id>c9c47490-cf0c-4ae1-bc0e-cfd015eb5c4a</id>
        <product_id>b8ca3a6e-72c0-11e4-efc6-455d6c270a5c</product_id>
        <name></name>
        <count>5</count>
        <received></received>
        <cost>2.5</cost>
    </products>
</Consignment>
```

Using Json.Net I get the following JSON from this (which is what I want):

```
{
    "id":"2b9b82c3-d446-4527-ae9e-a564f3f8306a",
    "name":"10/10/2014 15:45",
    "type":"OUTLET",
    "date":"2014-10-10T14:45:50",
    "outlet_id":"b8ca3a6e-72c0-11e4-efc6-455d6c2bd6f0",
    "source_outlet_id":"b8ca3a6e-72a9-11e4-efc6-50575111ef92",
    "status":"SENT",
    "products": [
    {
        "id":"2b9b82c3-d446-4527-ae9e-a564f3f8306a",
        "product_id":"b8ca3a6e-72c0-11e4-efc6-455d6c241252",
        "name":"",
        "count":"2",
        "received":"",
        "cost":"4"
    },
    {
        "id":"2b9b82c3-d446-4527-ae9e-a564f3f8306a",
        "product_id":"b8ca3a6e-72c0-11e4-efc6-455d6c270a5c",
        "name":"",
        "count":"5",
        "received":"",
        "cost":"2.5"
    }]
}
```

Using the JsonReaderWriterFactory instead of Json.Net I get this partially converted JSON-XML mix:

```
{
    "id":null,
    "name":null,
    "type":null,
    "date":null,
    "outlet_id":null,
    "source_outlet_id":null,
    "status":null,
    "products":null
}
0-10T14:43:14</date>
<outlet_id>b8ca3a6e-72c0-11e4-efc6-455d6c2bd6f0</outlet_id>
<source_outlet_id>b8ca3a6e-72a9-11e4-efc6-50575111ef92</source_outlet_id>
<status>SENT</status>
<products>
<id>c9c47490-cf0c-4ae1-bc0e-cfd015eb5c4a</id>
<product_id>b8ca3a6e-72c0-11e4-efc6-455d6c241252</product_id>
<name></name>
<count>2</count>
<received></received>
<cost>4</cost>
</products>
<products>
<id>c9c47490-cf0c-4ae1-bc0e-cfd015eb5c4a</id>
<product_id>b8ca3a6e-72c0-11e4-efc6-455d6c270a5c</product_id>
<name></name>
<count>5</count>
<received></received>
<cost>2.5</cost>
</products>
</Consignment>
```

The code I'm using for the conversion is:

```
string json = string.Empty;

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
streamWriter.Write(xml);
streamWriter.Flush();
stream.Position = 0;

using (XmlDictionaryWriter jsonWriter 
    = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(stream))
{
    var consignment = new Consignment();
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer =
        new DataContractJsonSerializer(consignment.GetType());
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, consignment);
    jsonWriter.Flush();
    json = Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Length);
}
```

My DataContract classes are:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Consignment")]
public class Consignment
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id", Order = 0)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name", Order = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "type", Order = 2)]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "date", Order = 3)]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "outlet_id", Order = 4)]
    public string OutletId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "source_outlet_id", Order = 5)]
    public string SourceOutletId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "status", Order = 6)]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "products", Order = 7)]
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name="products")]
public class Product
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id", Order = 0)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "product_id", Order = 1)]
    public string ProdutId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name", Order = 2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "count", Order = 3)]
    public int Count { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "received", Order = 4)]
    public int Received { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "cost", Order = 5)]
    public string Cost { get; set; }
}
```

What could be causing the interruption in the JSON conversion mid-stream?